# Launch libreoffice through matlab for ubuntu

Tags: linux, matlab, command-line, external, libreoffice

is there any way to use winopen or a similar function on matlab2017 for ubuntu? i'm trying to open my .xls file with libreoffice directly after a button have been pressed? or there is a way around it?

i already tried

```
system('libreoffice file.xls') 
system('xdg-open file.xls')
```

but somehow the libreoffice itself does not launch. The error occured is :

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3)

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3)
```

any solution guys?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try capturing the output of `system` and examining it for errors? Use this syntax: `[status,cmdout] = system(command)`.

Comment: the error itself is

    /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: 
    /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version 
    `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by 
    /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3)
    /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: 
    /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version 
    `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by 
    /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3)

Comment: This information is very relevant to your problem! Please use the [edit] feature and add it to the body of the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that by the time you invoke the `libreoffice` shell script, you have the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable set? If so, that may cause problems, if MATLAB ships a standard C++ library older than what LibreOffice expects.

Try creating a shell script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec libreoffice "$@"
```

Save it somewhere, mark it as executable, then invoke `/path/to/script` instead of `libreoffice` in your `system()` call. Does that solve the problem?